# Can XML properties of a BIRT report be gathered under a specific name?

Tags: xml, report, birt

I am trying to create BIRT Reports by writing XML code instead of drag and drop design method, using BIRT 4.4.2.

I would like to know if I can call the border properties with a name instead of writing the same XML property code for an element of report sharing exact same properties with the other one.

I have tried to call them with an ID value but could not make it work.

```
<property name="fontFamily">"Arial"</property>
<property name="fontWeight">bold</property>
<property name="color">#0000FF</property>
<property name="borderBottomStyle">none</property>
<property name="borderLeftStyle">none</property>
<property name="borderRightStyle">none</property>
<property name="borderTopStyle">none</property>
<property name="textAlign">center</property>
<property name="dataSet">Data Set</property>
```

For instance, I have lots of cells with no border styles so I want to use this XML many times but instead I want to call all the 8 lines with a single name like:

```
<property name="noBorderProperties"></property>
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this (in the BIRT designer as well) is to use styles.
E.g. create a style named "BlueBoldCenteredNoborder" and apply it to the cells.

Of course this doesn't work with the dataSet property, but this cannot be set for cells inside a grid/table anyway.